# sed (in bash) works with [ \t] but not with \s?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed, removing-whitespace

I want to search-replace something containing whitespace on a bash command line, and I assumed sed would be the easiest way to go.

Using `[ \t]` denoting either tab or space, to match the whitespace, works as intended:

```
echo "abc xyz" | sed "s/[ \t]xyz/123/"
abc123
```

But using `\s` instead of `[ \t]` does not, to my surprise:

```
echo "abc xyz" | sed "s/\sxyz/123/"
abc xyz
```

I'm fairly new to bash so I might be missing something trivial, but no matter what I do, I can't get this to work. Using `\\s` instead of `\s`, using single quotes (`'` instead of `"`), putting the whitespace marker inside square brackets (like `[\s]` or even `[\\s]`), nothing seems to help..?

(edit) in case it differs from one sed / bash version to another: I'm working on OS X here.

Additionally, I noticed that when I add a `+` after the `[ \t]` whitespace part, to optionally grab multiple space/tab characters if present, it doesn't work anymore either...??

```
echo "abc xyz" | sed "s/[ \t]+xyz/123/"
abc xyz
```

(and again, also tried with `\+` instead of `+`, and single quotes instead of double quotes, nothing helps)

Comment: Interesting and related: [How to match whitespace in sed?](http://superuser.com/a/112837/204979). Basically, _For POSIX compliance, use the character class [[:space:]] instead of \s, since the latter is a GNU sed extension_ So you are probably working in a non-GNU `sed`. Could you provide the output of `sed --version`?

Comment: on sed here, it works as expected; as @fedorqui suggest, it is gnu sed indeed

Comment: have you thoroughly read the sed man page on your system? It should document what does and does not work. Type `man sed` at a command prompt.

Comment: Ah, thanks, `sed --version` says `illegal option -- -` so I guess it's not GNU :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As seen in SuperUser's [How to match whitespace in sed?](https://superuser.com/a/112837/204979):

> For POSIX compliance, use the character class [[:space:]] instead of
>   \s, since the latter is a GNU sed extension

So you are probably running a non-GNU `sed` version, hence `\s` not working to you.

You have two solutions:

- To use  (space) and `\t` together, like you were doing.
- To use `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: Confirmed, thanks, it works with [[:space:]]
However, the + modifer still doesn't work, any ideas?

Note that `[[:space:]]\{1,999\}` *does* work, but `[[:space:]]+` or `[[:space:]]\+` do not.

Comment: To use `+` normally you need either to escape it: `\+` or to use `-r` for extended regex: `sed -r "s/[[:space:]]+/X/"`

Comment: @RocketNuts the [POSIX-compliant syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) for _one or more matches_ Is `\{1,\}` - anything else is an extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'abc xyz<>abcxyz' | sed 's/[[:space:]]xyz/123/g'
abc123<>abcxyz
echo 'abc xyz<>abcxyz' | sed "s/[[:space:]]xyz/123/g"
abc123<>abcxyz
```

doesn't work on very old sed version but fine on GNU sed as posix complaint (AIX, ...)